# Can't make buttons to appear (wxpython) on ubuntu

Tags: python

```
try:
    import wx
except ImportError:
    print 'Module not found'

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(parent,id ):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        button = wx.Button(panel,label = 'close',size = (50,50))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.OnCloseMe,button)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE,self.OnCloseWindow)

    def OnCloseMe(self,event):
        self.Close(True)

    def OncloseWindow(self,event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(parent = None, id =-1,title = 'Widget',size = (300,100))
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Hi guys ,the code above is just to create a button in wxpython.but everytime i run the code ,only the Frame appears,no buttons or whatsoever inside,just blank.i tried to reinstall the wxpython module but no luck.
My second question is whenever i try to initialize say, title = 'widget', size= (300,100) in the frame constructor like wx.Frame.**init**(self,parent,id,title ='widget',size = (300,100) it does not work, i have to do it through this line: 
frame = wx.Frame(parent = None, id =-1,title = 'Widget',size = (300,100))
why is that so.thaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working code just add your events to it. Also consider using [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/) to design graphically your gui instead of writing it:

```
import wx
import gettext

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        kwds["style"] = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.panel_1 = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.button_1 = wx.Button(self.panel_1, wx.ID_ANY, _("button_1"))

        self.__set_properties()
        self.__do_layout()

    def __set_properties(self):
        self.SetTitle(_("frame_1"))

    def __do_layout(self):
        sizer_1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer_2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer_2.Add(self.button_1, 0, 0, 0)
        self.panel_1.SetSizer(sizer_2)
        sizer_1.Add(self.panel_1, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0)
        self.SetSizer(sizer_1)
        sizer_1.Fit(self)
        self.Layout()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    gettext.install("app")

    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    wx.InitAllImageHandlers()
    frame_1 = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame_1)
    frame_1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you. I do appreciate the help:)

Comment: Yeah absolutely.How do i do that again?by clicking on the star by the right side of my question?

Comment: by clicking on the up arrow and the right sign next to the answer but this only if my answer was useful for you @
user2983686

Comment: Thanks for your patience.I just did